# Prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to 2}f(x)=3.$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let: $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
5-x,  & \text{if $x$ is irrational.} \\[2ex]
1+x, & \text{if $x$ is rational.}
\end{cases}$$

- Prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to 2}f(x)=3.$
- Prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}f(x) $ doesn't exist.

Solution Attempt: I want to use the definition of continuity. by saying that for each each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $|x-2|<\delta$  $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$. and somehow I thought about using the qualities of $|f(x)|$ and try to get that an equation that might help me in the proof. but got stuck there. any help?

Comment: If for every sequence ${x_n}$ converging to $x$, the sequence ${f(x_n)}$ converges to $f(x)$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: @vnd At least for first countable spaces, like $\Bbb R$.

Comment: السلام dear Abdel Ghani  $|f(x)-3|=|x-2|$ so you can choose $\delta\leq\epsilon$.

Comment: for the second part take $x_{n}=1/n$ and $y_{n}=\frac{\sqrt2}{n}$ then $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ approach $0$ while $f(X_{n})$ tends to $1$ and $f(y_{n})$ approaches $5$.

Comment: @M.R.Yegan Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Related:For the first question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475703/nowhere-continuous-function-limit and for the second question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417219/proof-for-dirichlet-function-and-discontinuous