# Prove that $f(x)=\begin{cases}1& \text{if x is rational},\\0 &\text{if x is irrational}\end{cases}$ is discontinuous at every real number.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1& \text{if x is rational},\\0 &\text{if x is irrational.}\end{cases}$$

Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at every real number. I realize that if $x_0\in\Bbb{R} $, then every neighborhood of $x_0$ contains rational points (at which $f(x)=1$) and contains irrational points (at which $f(x)=0$). I see that the existence of $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is also in question. From here, I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How do you define the limit?

Comment: what is the definition of a continuous function?

Comment: @ John Ma: I've just edited the question!

Comment: So what is your definition of continuous function?

Comment: Too many Mikes here :) The one who asked the definition of a continuous function (to guide the OP) and who is writing this is not the OP Mike

Comment: Oops. Yes I am confused..... @mike and mike...

Comment: I am not Mike. I also concur: we are going to need a definition of continuity to make progress.

Comment: it is continuous with limit 1 in the rationals and continuous with limit 0 in the irrationals.

Comment: But yes once we have a definition of continuity this question is pretty much done (not the OP Mike)

Comment: @Name-sake, $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in\Bbb{R}$ if $\forall\;\epsilon>0,$ $\exists \;\delta>0$ s.t. $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$, with $|x-x_0|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

Comment: We clearly don't have that though (your def'n of continuity)

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ does nowhere exist because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$

Comment: One can do something different than the proof given at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417219/proof-for-dirichlet-function-and-discontinuous and use the topological definition of continuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ so for $x_0$ being irrational we have  a sequence of rational terms $(a_n)$ convergent to $x_0$. Now if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then

$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(x_0)=0$$
which is a contradiction. Same reasoning for $x_0$ being rational and by using that $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is also dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The crucial point is that, in any interval, not matter how small, there are both rational and irrational numbers.

Answer (score 4):

> **Main idea:** Choose any arbitrary $c\in\Bbb{R}$ and then show that the function $f$ is discontinuous at $c$. What we shall do is- we
>   shall try  find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\Bbb{R}$ converging to $c$,
>   but the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}$ does not converge to $f(c)$. But to do
>   this, we need to consider two cases- either $c\in\Bbb{Q}$ or
>   $c\notin\Bbb{Q}$. So, let us proceed...

**CASE $1$**:  $c\in\Bbb{Q}$
Let us define a sequence $\{a_n\}$ by $a_n:=c-{\sqrt 2 \over n}\:\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$
It is easy to see that, $a_n\in\Bbb{R}\backslash\Bbb{Q}\:\:\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$ and hence $f(a_n)=0\:\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$ $\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=0\ne1=f(c)$
Again, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(c-{\sqrt 2 \over n})=c$
Thus, we get a sequence $\{a_n\}$, which converges to c, but the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}$ does not converge to $f(c)$. So, we are done for $c\in\Bbb{Q}$.
**CASE $2$**:  $c\in\Bbb{R}\backslash\Bbb{Q}$
Now, since $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, we can get a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of rational numbers which converges to $c$. Thus $\lim f(a_n)=1\ne 0=f(c)$. So, we are done for $c\in\Bbb{R}\backslash\Bbb{Q}$ also.
Thus, we get for any $c\in\Bbb{R}$, $f$ is discontinuous at $c$.
Since $c\in\Bbb{R}$ is arbitrary, $f$ is discontinuous $\forall c\in\Bbb{R}$ i.e. $f$ is discontinuous on the whole real line.
N.B. This type of function is known as *[Dirichlet Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function)* which is nowhere continuous.

Comment: You rightly deserve the point! Thank you for this awesome answer!

Comment: wait but in case 2, $a_n $ is irrational for every $n$ and converges to an irrational, so $\lim a_n = c$ and $\lim f(a_n) = 0 = f(c)$

Comment: @dude3221, you got the point, thank you. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a different take on this problem:

A function ${\displaystyle f:X\rightarrow Y}$ is continuous at a point ${\displaystyle x\in X}$ if and only if ${\displaystyle f^{-1}(V)}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ for every neighborhood $V$ of ${\displaystyle f(x)}$ in $Y$.

Take any arbitrary point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider a neighborhood of $f(x)$. Consider the neighborhood $V_1=(.5,1.5)$ or the neighborhood $V_2=(-.5,.5)$. We know that $f(x)$ is in one of those open sets. But then $f^{-1}(V)$ is not a neighborhood at all. $f^{-1}(V_1)$ are only rational values and  $f^{-1}(V_2)$ are only irrational values. Neither of these could be a neighborhood in the reals because every open ball in the reals contains both rational and irrational values.

Comment: For the sake of continuity (and apparently bad puns) with my previous comments: It depends what definition (of continuity) you want to use.